# How can I find out the cache hit rate when I run a program on Apple M1?

Tags: c, caching, memory, apple-m1

How can I find out the cache hit rate when I run a program on Apple M1?

I would like to check the cache hit rate of a program written in C to avoid memory rate limitation, but I don't know how to check the hit rate.
I would like to know how to check the hit rate.

Environment:

- M1 Max
- 64GB
- Ventura 13.1

I thought I could find out by using a debugger such as GDB, but could not.

Comment: There is nothing in the arm64 architecture that I'm aware of that would allow you to measure the cache hit rate. So you'd have to either resort to some sort of cache timing side channel attack, or run your code in an emulator (but then you'd have the issue of needing an emulator that accurately emulates Apple Silicon).